# Toolbar Android 4.0 - 5.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

Is There a way to make compatible toolbar in 4.0 and 5.0 android app?
I'm developing an android app and my activity extends AppCompatActivity and I'm using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0', but in 4.0 versione toolbar doesn't show and actionbar is null.

I do not know how to fix without totally changing the code.

this is my toolbar code xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    compat:showAsAction="always"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/maroon"
        android:textColorPrimary="@color/maroon"
        android:textColorSecondary="@color/maroon"
        android:actionMenuTextColor="@color/maroon"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

..activity code:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

....style code:

```
 <!-- ToolBar -->
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/maroon</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/maroon</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/maroon</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/tw__solid_white</item>
</style>


  <style name="AppTheme_noAction" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It depends, Would you add some codes? - `I do not know how to fix without totally changing the code` & Unfortunately, We don't know how we can help you without seeing any codes ???

Comment: Can you update you style and xml where you added toolbar ?

Comment: I modified my post and added code.